# Get bounding box for SVG path using jQuery

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I want to get the getBBox() for svg path in jquery. i tried like this

```
$("#"+ path id)[0].getBBox() -> returns x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0
```

I have added the path to an SVG element. I tried some other element in SVG, for example text node in that case it returns the some bounding box value.

How can I calculate the bounding box for a path in SVG?

```
<path id="container_svg_John_0" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="url(#container_svg_John0Gradient)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M -2390.2 -125.8888888888889 L 0 0 M 0 0 L 251.60000000000002 -45.77777777777778 M 251.60000000000002 -45.77777777777778 L 503.20000000000005 -11.444444444444445 M 503.20000000000005 -11.444444444444445 L 629 -183.11111111111111 "/>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find inspiration in this simple utility which lets you enter a path and then shows the bounding box. http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/vNoemp/

Answer (score 13):

getBBox is a native SVG method and isn't part of jquery so you would need to write

```
$("#"+ path id)[0].getBBox()
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/pGBuj/)

If you're getting a non-zero value for the example and a zero value in your code then there must be something else going on that you've not shown us.

The most likely causes are that the path is a child of `<defs>` i.e. you're only using it indirectly in a pattern or clipPath or alternatively the it has a display style of none in which case it wouldn't be rendered so would have no bounding box.

Comment: it was bad solution/response.i already know about that and also tried like this but it still returns zero.

Comment: in which case it will returns "0" value. i tried for rect element too but it returns "zero" only in all browsers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393361/getbbox-returns-nothing-for-rect-or-path

Comment: If I click on the "example" link in the answer I gave above using Firefox I get -2390. Are you saying that using Firefox and clicking on the link you get 0?

Comment: for me this also returns "-2390" in all browsers. but in my project i am debugging the value that time it returns "zero" i also added this to svg object. i dont know the exact cause ? may i know in which case it returns "zero"

Comment: It would return 0 if the rect/path had a style of display:none or was a child of <defs> as in neither of those cases is the rect/path actually drawn.

Comment: i want to get the rectangle or box for grouped svg path. please refer below jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gFJyC/

Comment: Works for me on Firefox i.e. does not display 0 when I modified the jsfiddle to use jquery 1.9.1 (select from dropdown on top left).

Answer (score 10):

<s>The `getBBox()` native implementation in Webkit is buggy, you can find the [bug tracker here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53512)</s>. Actually It's **fixed** now

A solution is to use an SVG library that has it's own algorithms for calculating such matters, one of them is [Raphael.js](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

You could make use of *Raphael's* [`element.getBBox()`](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.getBBox), which does the same thing as the native `getBBox()`.

Comment: Actually, [it doesn't work on Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230599). The [sample there](http://granite.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/B/bbox2.3.svg) shows the issue and the differences between current Chrome version (45) and latest IE/FF.

Comment: Chrome is correct now - the discrepancy in the sample posted in the comment above is due to stroke width.

Answer (score 6):

I too am having a hard time getting the JQuery syntax to work for me. This returned **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getBBox'**:

```
console.log($("#testtext").getBBox().width);
```

... because I had omitted the array index (thanks @Christian Vielma, below)!

However standard Javascript worked for me and I was able to display the width of the (in my case) RECT in the Chrome console:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("testtext").getBBox().width);
```

So you might try that instead.

Comment: I believe you have to use $('#testtext')[0].getBBox().width

Comment: just to clarify, both `$('#testtext')[0]` ([jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery()/)) and `document.getElementById("testtext")` return a DOM element object, which, then, natively supports `getBBox().width` on [svg elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement)

Answer (score 0):

Try Element.getBoundingClientRect().  It's from the html DOM, but works for me on SVG elements (without much transformation).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to make sure is that your svg is added to the DOM and not detached. Also make sure that your SVG element