# getBBox() returns nothing for rect or path

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

Please refer below rect code.

```
<rect id="container_svg_ChartArea" x="146.8" y="20" width="633.2" height="414" fill="White" stroke-width="1" stroke="Gray"></rect>
```

i tried get the rectangle bounding box value it returns nothing i.e."0" for x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0

```
$("#container_svg_ChartArea")[0].getBBox()
```

but when i get the attribute for x/y/width/height it returns some value

```
$("#container_svg_ChartArea").attr("x") ->value returned.
```

same for path element as well as rectangle element.

what is going wrong?

no solution provide here.

[how to get bounding box or rect (getBBox()) for svg path in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377186/how-to-get-bounding-box-or-rect-getbbox-for-svg-path-in-jquery)

thats why i created another thread. it is not duplicate thread.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get bounding box or rect (getBBox()) for svg path in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377186/how-to-get-bounding-box-or-rect-getbbox-for-svg-path-in-jquery)

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with your bug, your code works correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/duopixel/UdLtx/

Comment: i want to get the rectangle or box for grouped svg path. please refer below jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/gFJyC/

Comment: document.querySelector("#container_svg_ChartArea").getBBox();

Answer (score 0):

Look this example on how to get and manage the bounding box of svg elements

http://www.janvas.com/illustrators_designers_developers/projects/janvas2D_web/examples_EN.php?exampleName=ufo_animation_EN

in general

```
var svgElement = document.getElementById('the id of your element');
bbox = svgElement.getBBox();

console.log( bbox.x ) ;
console.log( bbox.y ) ;
console.log( bbox.width ) ;   
console.log( bbox.height ) ;
```