# How to make a SVG container hug its contents?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on a project where some SVG tags are auto-generated based on the user provided input. For instance the most common scenario I have is that I may have many SVG objects (i.e. rect, ellipse, polygon, etc.) inside a `<svg>` container.

Now the issue is that my container SVG has a certain length and width regardless of its contents. I am trying to make my container SVG tag to only have so much length and width so that it can contain its content but no blank space.

For example: [in this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sunnysinghthakran/Ln9qH/) the SVG with `id=svg1` is much larger than its contents need it to be.

How can i make the SVG container of appropriate size?

Note: I don't know which shapes are going to be put inside the SVG container and where they  are going to be placed. Also, the SVG can contain another `<svg>` tag inside it and shapes can be inside this inner SVG.

Note 2: In some cases the width and height of the SVG container may be needed to be increased so as to not truncate the contents. Alos, it is imperative that i only use a pure HTML/CSS solution for certaion reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get bounding box or rect (getBBox()) for svg path in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377186/how-to-get-bounding-box-or-rect-getbbox-for-svg-path-in-jquery)

Comment: If you can't use javascript I suspect the only option would be to abandon using `<svg>` elements and use `<g>` elements instead as they autosize to their contents.

Comment: @RobertLongson But somewhere as the base tag i still would have to use a svg tag, and that container svg tag will not autosize to its `<g>` childs even if `<g>` themselves are hugging their contents.

Comment: Just make the <svg> very big. It doesn't render so I don't see what the problem is. Otherwise you've painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: @RobertLongson well thats the one thing that actually prompted me to ask this question. Big svg tags tend to push any other HTML elements away from the shapes inside the SVG. So if i want a SVG shape immediately followed by a `<p>` tag, i would either have to make a svg text element or make do with a badly designed page. Since the HTML is auto-generated, i don't have the flexibility to follow the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if i understood it well, then you want your 'svg tag' of exact 'height' and 'width' in which its 'child' resides.

one possible solution would be:-

(assuming your svg is positioned at 0,0)

1. you need to track which element is drawn in your svg (i hope you are already doing this).
2. then you need to use 'getBbox()' to get its 'height' and 'width'
3. Now here you need to calculate the exact position of your 'child' element with respect to position (0,0).

**lets take an example**

```
var svgwidth=500;
var svgheight=500;

<svg id="svg1" width="500" height="500">
</svg>
```

now let say user draw a rectangle in it.

```
<rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="300"></rect>
```

now we need to determine exact 'width' and 'height' for our 'svg'.

```
var rect1=document.getElementById('rect1');
var bbox=rect1.getBBox();

var widtharea=bbox.x+bbox.width;
var heightarea=bbox.y+bbox.height;
```

Now compare 'widtharea' with 'svgwidth', if its larger then 'svgwidth', update value of 'svgwidth'. similarly compare 'heightarea' with 'svgheight'

you need to perform above step every time user create any element in svg.

Comment: ok, one thing that i think i should have mentioned earlier is that, i only need a pure HTML/CSS solution for this. I can't use javascript or any other script that will be visible at the client-side.

Comment: HTML/CSS are also client side  :-)  . Secondly, handling svg with 'CSS' has many limitations.

Comment: You said that the "SVG tags are auto-generated based on the user provided input".  Doesn't that imply client side javascript is being used?